# Any way to route to a default template using ui-sref without state defined?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a series of states like so:

```
.state('welcome', {
        url: "^/welcome",
        views: {
            "@": {
                templateUrl: "components/welcome/welcome.html",
                controller: "WelcomeController as welcome"
            }
        }
 })
.state('welcome.step1', {
    templateUrl: "components/welcome/welcome.step1.html"
})
.state('welcome.step2', {
    templateUrl: "components/welcome/welcome.step2.html"
})
```

In my view, I can use `ui-sref="welcome.step2"` to move from Step 1 to Step 2.

However its seems like overkill to define states for each Step when the file structure implies the state.

I thought the router was smart enough to do that, but I may be thinking of **ng-route**.

Is there a way to avoid defining simple routes like this with a single template for each?

Comment: `templateUrl` accepts a function

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop to define your states:

```
for (var step = 1; step <= 10; step++) {
     $stateProvider.state('welcome.step' + step, {
         templateUrl: "components/welcome/welcome.step" + step + ".html"
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my views to step1, step2 for simplification. My actual routes use names, so incrementing the # wouldn't solve it for me. I thought there may have been a default mechanism to determine a route using the file format. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If there is a standard way to deduce the templateUrl from the state name, then put your state names in an array, create a function stateNameToTemplateUrl(), and loop through the array to generate all the states, with their templateUrl, thanks to that function.